# Eastern European alphabet conversion from nb to PDF

Tags: export, pdf-format

When converting Eastern European alphabet written article from .nb to pdf, certain letters convert to empty rectangle like shapes or constructs, also hacek like letters (č,ć,ž,š,""...). Has anybody suggestion how to correct this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on 9.0.1 Win 8.1 x64. `Export["easternEuropean.pdf", EvaluationNotebook[]];Export["easternEuropean.png", Import[%]];` gives me [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2NsPV.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem 9.0.1, OS X 10.9.  All of Latin-2 works fine.   I remember that this was a problem in v6 or v7 with Windows XP, as I do use Latin-2 characters myself.  But it's been fixed in v8 or before.  What version are you using and how are you exporting precisely?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this problem on OS X with the current version of Mathematica (9.0.1).

However, I *think* I remember a similar problem existing in some earlier versions of Mathematica, at least on Windows.  If my memory is correct, a possible solution was to use one of the PDF printers (Acrobat Distiller, [redmon](https://www.stat.tamu.edu/~henrik/GSWriter/GSWriter.html), etc.) to print the notebook to PDF instead of using Save As ... PDF.

But then it is possible that I remember wrong.